# Wifi signal strength and internet connection is slow

Tags: wireless-networking, signal-strength

I hope that I have asked this question in the right topic.

Basically I use BT (In the U.K.) and I have problems with my router receiving a weak signal in certain rooms of the house, which, therefore makes the internet really slow in some cases it won't work at all.

I have had experience working with Virgin Media (UK) before and just changed the channel number and this worked fine, but, do not know if I would receive the same outcome on BT.

Could anyone suggest any other things that I could try alongside of the channel change in order to /hopefully/ get a stronger signal, without having to install Ethernet cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- move the router
- buy a [repeater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater)
- buy [homeplug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeplug)
- drape tinfoil over your home to block neighbours wifi
- demolish interior walls and floors
- read a [magazine](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2372811,00.asp)

Obviously, some of these are easier to run past the wife than others.

Comment: I was after some serious responses, but I'm going to suggest that I drape tinfoil over my house to my landlords, see if they will go with this!

Answer (score 1):

The Three (3) Wall Rule and Wireless Penetration

Background

Please note ISM band wireless technology (2.4 and 5.8 GHz) has physical limitations when it comes to penetration through walls.

I have even seen experienced engineers stuff this up. This is very bad for business. People see wireless as this invisible medium and sometimes associate it with magic. It’s not magic and has limitations which should clearly be spelt out so that clients’ expectations are matched.

Scenarios

1. No wall. This is called line of sight. Wireless requires line of sight due to the physics of the medium. Radio waves do not penetrate walls but if there are no walls they propagate nicely. If there are no walls you will have Great Service.
2. One wall. There will be Normal Service, and it will work fine.
3. Two walls.There will be service, and it should be okay. It’s called Okay Service.
4. Three walls. Service will vary between just working to terrible. It’s called Poor / Terrible Service.
5. Four walls and more. Even though you might see a signal, you will have absolutely horrendous service. Do not go there as you will destroy the client’s expectations and they will continuously log support calls to sort something out that we can’t.

If you know these basics you can do almost any site survey, and you can even encourage clients to do their own site survey for quantity and position of APs. Please note however that there is a difference between a window, a concrete slab, and a normal wall. If you are unsure please leave this up to an expert.